# two images is loaded instead of one when first socket connects - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I'm trying to implement a multiplayer feature to my game. I'm using `node.js` for this. When one person connects, an image is supposed to be loaded to the browser. Instead it loads two images.

Heres is part of my class

```
var count = 0;          //Keep track of which player we're oparating on
function Car(id){
    var that = this;    //Reference to 'this'

    this.loadHero = function(){
        that.id = document.getElementById(id); //Store the id of our charakter
        $(that.id).css({"display" : "block"});
    }
}
```

node.js on client side:

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

    socket.on('entrance', function(data){
        console.log(data.message);
        var num = (count > 0) ? count : '';
        console.log("hero" + num);
        var hero = new Car("hero" + num);
        hero.init();
        count++;
    });
```

When i start my server and connect. My console shows me the following

[image]

`hero` is the id of my first image (first player the connects). `hero1` is the second player and so on. So I don't understand why both my images is loaded when one player connects.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: I have experienced an extra request in Node.js, requesting favicon. Check whether it happens in your case too.

Comment: @lexasss thanks for the tip - I'll be sure to check it out!

Comment: A note: Why do you use `var that = this;` in this case?  If you create a `Car` with `new Car` then this does not make much sense in that context. It for sure would make sense if you pass `aCar.loadHero` as callback somewhere, but probably a `aCar.loadHero.bind(aCar)` is a better choice then.

Comment: @t.niese I agree it doesn't make much sense there, but like I wrote, its just a small part of a much bigger class :) Do you have any input on the actual question? It looks like lexasss was right, but I haven't figured out how to fix it...

Comment: @lexasss I checked out what you said, and that seems to be what's causing it. I still haven't figured out how to get around it though. Any advice?