# Prevent favicon.ico from making a second request - Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io, node.js-connect

I'm trying to prevent **favicon.ico** form making a second request when a socket connects.

Here is my server:

```
var io = require('socket.io'),
connect = require('connect');

var app = connect()
.use(connect.static('public'))
.use(function(req, res, next){
    if (req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'} );
        next();
    }
})
.use(function(req, res){
    res.end('stupid favicon...');   
}).listen(3000);

var game = io.listen(app);

game.sockets.on('connection', function(socket){
    socket.emit('entrance', {message: 'Welcome to the game!'});

    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
        game.sockets.emit('exit', {message: 'A player left the game...!'});
    });
    game.sockets.emit('entrance', {message: 'Another gamer is online!'});
});
```

This does not seem to work. I get no errors, but when one socket connects, two images is loaded from the client side, which makes it seem like there is still two requests happening.

So is my code completely wrong, or am I on the right track? Because no matter what I `console.log()` in my server-code, nothing is printed to the console.

**EDIT: Client side**

```
var socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000');

    socket.on('entrance', function(data){
        console.log(data.message);

        var num = (count > 0) ? count : '';
        console.log("hero" + num);

        var hero = new Car("hero" + num);
        hero.init();

        count++;
    });
```

`count` is global. I have (for now two images), one `#hero` and `#hero1`. When one player connects both images are loaded.

Comment: Can you show your client side code, which image is loaded there twice ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're not supposed to call `next` when you want to respond to a request.  Generally, it's not valid to `writeHead()` and then call `next`.  Most middleware expects to work with a response that has not written to the network yet.

The reason your "stupid favicon" middleware runs is that *you're calling it* it by invoking `next` in the first one.  You need to `res.writeHead()` and `res.end()` **OR** just call `next`.

```
function(req, res, next){
    if (req.url === '/favicon.ico') {
        res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'image/x-icon'} );
        res.end(/* icon content here */);
    } else {
        next();
    }
}
```

Alternatively, just use [the builtin favicon middleware](http://www.senchalabs.org/connect/middleware-favicon.html), which does important things like setting proper `Cache-Control` headers.

Comment: thanks a lot. But My code still seems to call two images after only one socket connects. I don't know if this is the favicon.ico's fault anymore. Would you mind taking a  quick look at my previous post? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19202615/two-images-is-loaded-instead-of-one-when-first-socket-connects-node-js